# Hand scribble effect without using modifier

Tags: export, effects, gltf

[image]

I know I could easily achieve this kind of effect using Build modifier.

but I realize I can't export the animation using modifiers into gltf.

Is there any other way or idea that doesn't have to use any modifiers to get this effect?

I tried search but couldn't get any. I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: To export animation to glTF, you need either Bones or Shape Keys (aka Morph targets). But I don't know how to easily reproduce this effect using them.